# How to add http_referer to a cookie?

Tags: nginx

I was trying something like this:

```
map $http_referer $setCookie {
        default                "referrer={$http_referer};Domain=.verbalink.com";
        ~*test1\.com           "referrer=bl;Domain=.verbalink.com;Max-Age=31536000";

}

server{
    add_header Set-Cookie $setCookie;
}
```

But when the cookie is created it has `${http_referer}` as the value not the actual http referer.  I also tried `{$http_referer}` and `$http_referer` but none worked.  How can I get the referer into my Cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map $http_referer $setCookie {
    default       $http_referer;
    ~*test1\.com  "bl;Max-Age=31536000";
}

server{
    add_header Set-Cookie "referrer=$setCookie;Domain=.verbalink.com";
}
```

*The resulting value can be a string or another variable.* © http://nginx.org/r/map

vs.

*value can contain variables*  © http://nginx.org/r/add_header

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two entries i would map them into some keywords and then in server entry you can If them :) and it should work. So it would look like:

```
      map $http_referer $setCookie {
            default                "def";
            ~*test1\.com           "test";
    }

    server{
if ($setCookie == "def"){
add_header Set-Cookie "referrer=$http_referer;Domain=.verbalink.com";
} 
if ($setCookie == "test"){
add_header Set-Cookie "referrer=bl;Domain=.verbalink.com;Max-Age=31536000";
} 

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will have about 20 entries.  Either way, I have tried the `$http_referer` method, but it literally shows up as `$http_referer` in my cookie.